# How to know entire website size using wget?

Tags: wget

I can use `wget -r 'url'`. But I don't know the size that will be downloaded. I use `wget --spider 'url'` to know a webpage size and when I use `wget -r --spider 'url'` it checks all page recursively and return each file size that I don't want, I want only the entire(cumulative of each) size.

Answer (score 0):

```
SUM=0; for BYTES in `wget --spider -r 'url' 2>&1 | grep Length | cut -d " " -f 2`; do let SUM=$SUM+$BYTES; done; echo "$SUM"
```

Comment: Welcome to [ubuntu.se]! Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.